# How to get Mono running on ARM/Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono, arm, abi

I've got a small board called "Udoo" (http://www.udoo.org), which is running a Linux distribution based on Ubuntu 12.04.
For development I would like to install a recent version of Mono. Currently only 2.x is installed, which is pretty buggy.

I tried to follow the instructions on the Mono homepage (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/):

> To enable installation on older Ubuntu releases such as Ubuntu 12.04
>   and Ubuntu 12.10 (and their derivatives), you will need to add a
>   second repository to your system, in addition to the generic
>   Debian/Ubuntu repository (if you don’t use sudo, be sure to switch to
>   root):
>
> echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian
>   wheezy-libtiff-compat main" | sudo tee -a
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list

Then I did "sudo apt-get update", to update the package lists.
This resulted in an error:

> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/dists/wheezy-libtiff-compat/InRelease
>   Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' in Release
>   file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

D'oh! I though this armhf-problem was solved months ago?
Can anyone give me a hint on how to get the latest version of Mono for ARM/Linux?

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue with a microzed